# Calling src from nearest audio tag to JavaScript function without ID

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to play multiple locally stored mp3 files on a single html page. I want a single JavaScript function in a separate js file triggered `onclick` that will play the correct file referenced in the adjacent audio tag. The audio just needs to play through once every time it is tapped/clicked.

I've tried using `querySelector` and various other techniques to find the nearest audio tag, but it always defaults to the audio tag at the top of the page. How can I limit the scope of querySelect, or is there another method of doing what I want? I don't want to have to create a unique ID for every audio tag because there are dozens of pages like this I am making.

```js
function PlaySound() {
  var sound = document.querySelector(".audio");
  sound.play()
}
```

```html
<audio class="audio" src="../../audio/na.mp3" autostart="false"></audio><a onclick="PlaySound()">나</a>

<audio class="audio" src="../../audio/gak.mp3" autostart="false"></audio><a onclick="PlaySound()">각</a>
```

Comment: need something unique, how does system know on which audio tag you need to give sound?

Comment: what you mean by nearest? do you want to get the last audio tag?

Comment: So each audio tag will have its own respective script tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use a `button`, not an anchor tag for these. They are buttons, since they only do an action on the page. Links are something that takes you to another page.

Now for your issue: when an event listener is invoked, such as your `PlaySound` when `onclick` happens, you can give it a `this` argument, which is the DOM instance of the button clicked.

Now your audio is a simple `previousElementSibling` away from grabbing, meaning and you can easily invoke `audio.play()` on it.

```js
function play (button) {
  console.log('Button:', button.innerText)
  const audio = button.previousElementSibling
  console.log('Audio', audio)
}
```

```html
<audio src="1"></audio>
<button onclick="play(this)">1</button>

<audio src="2"></audio>
<button onclick="play(this)">2</button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this all, particularly the const variable, but it does work like you said so thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is store the information that are held by the audio tags inside a JavaScript `array` and dynamically create the list of audio and the respective buttons.

```js
var audioList = [{
  src: "../../audio/na.mp3",
  text: "나"
}, {
  src: "../../audio/gak.mp3",
  text: "각"
}];

var container = document.querySelector("#container");

audioList.forEach(function(audio) {
  var audioElem = document.createElement("audio");
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  audioElem.setAttribute("autostart", false);
  audioElem.setAttribute("src", audio.src);
  button.textContent = audio.text;
  audioElem.className = "audio";
  button.addEventListener("click", getButtonListener(audioElem));
  container.appendChild(audioElem);
  container.appendChild(button);
});

function getButtonListener(audioElem) {
  return function() {
    audioElem.play();
    console.log("Playing:" + audioElem.src);
  };
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Or you could just do:

```js
var audioList = {
  "나": "../../audio/na.mp3",
  "각": "../../audio/gak.mp3"
};

function openAudio(target){
 document.querySelector("audio[src='" + audioList[target.textContent] + "']").play();
 console.log("Playing: " + audioList[target.textContent]);
}
```

```html
<audio class="audio" src="../../audio/na.mp3" autostart="false"></audio>
<button onclick="openAudio(this)">나</button>

<audio class="audio" src="../../audio/gak.mp3" autostart="false"></audio>
<button onclick="openAudio(this)">각</button>
```